# What is the use of alert-dismissible

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am creating an alert box using bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show">
            Alert  <a href="#" class="alert-link">Read this message</a><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> Close </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
</body>
</html>
```

This code works in same way if I remove alert-dissmissible class for the div. If there is no change even after removing alert-dissmissible class declaration then What is the use of alert-dissmissible class? The alert box is dissmissible even if the alert box does'nt has alert-dissmissible class.Why?

Comment: read [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) what are alert and what are dismissible alert. Just a quick google search for "bootstrap alert dismissible" to get the answer

Comment: _"Add a dismiss button and the .alert-dismissible class, **which adds extra padding to the right of the alert and positions the .close button.**"_ - [The Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing)

Answer (score 0):

The following is from the Bootstrap [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing)

> Using the alert JavaScript plugin, it’s possible to dismiss any alert
> inline. Here’s how:
>
> - Be sure you’ve loaded the alert plugin, or the compiled Bootstrap
> - JavaScript. If you’re building our JavaScript from source, it requires
>   util.js. The compiled version includes this.
> - Add a dismiss button and
>   the .alert-dismissible class, which adds extra padding to the right of
>   the alert and positions the .close button.
> - On the dismiss button, add
>   the data-dismiss="alert" attribute, which triggers the JavaScript
>   functionality. Be sure to use the  element with it for proper
>   behavior across all devices.
> - To animate alerts when dismissing them,
>   be sure to add the .fade and .show classes.